# Multiple event handler firings, why?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I have a tough time trying to solve this problem. I have been at for 3 hours, and still I couldn't find out why it is doing this. Here is the code:

```
private void Catagory_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedCategoryId = categoryIdList[categoryListBox.SelectedIndex];

        client.GetItemsAsync(selectedCategoryId);
        client.GetItemsCompleted += 
            new EventHandler<GetItemsCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetItemsCompleted);
    }

void client_GetItemsCompleted(object sender, GetItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        itemIdList.Clear();
        itemNameList.Clear();
        itemNumberList.Clear();
        itemDisplayList.Clear(); //Clears the Display List Items

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            itemIdList = e.ItemIDList;
            itemNumberList = e.itemNumber;
            itemNameList = e.Result;

            for (int i = 0; i < itemIdList.Count; i++)
            {
                itemDisplayList.Add(new ItemDisplay { itemNumber = itemNumberList[i], itemName = itemNameList[i] });
            }

            //Populating the listbox controll with the itemDisplaylist...
            Items.ItemsSource = itemDisplayList;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem in getting the items list.");
        }
    }
```

When I change the category the first time it works perfectly. By perfectly, I mean that it calls the function `GetItemsAsync(selectedCategoryId)` and grabs the results and calls the event handler `client_GetItemsCompleted()` and the inner working of the event handler works as it is supposed to, it sets the lists with the proper data and displays the itemNumber and the itemName in the list box . But, when I change the category again to get different items, it doesn't work properly, what it's doing is that it clears the lists and populates the lists as it is supposed to, runs the for loop and populates the listBox called `Items` but for some reason it goes to the top of the function again and empties all the lists. Please tell my why it is executing the function again? And when I choose another category again, it executes the event handler 3 times and then 4 times and so on. Wnow why it is doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everytime this is executed:

```
  client.GetItemsCompleted +=
```

You add a subscriber to the event, so the second time it will fire twice (the third time triple times, etc..).

Either unsubscrice ( -= ) in the completed method:

```
void client_GetItemsCompleted(object sender, GetItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try {
       /* .... */
    }
    finally {
        client.GetItemsCompleted -= 
            new EventHandler<GetItemsCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetItemsCompleted);
    }
}
```

or initiate the client object before every call.

```
var client = new ...();
client.GetItemsAsync(selectedCategoryId);
client.GetItemsCompleted += 
            new EventHandler<GetItemsCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetItemsCompleted);
```

Comment: im sorry but where would i unsubscribe it?? where should i write the code `client.GetItemsCompleted -=` and how would i write it can you tell, i haven't really done that before

Comment: It is not a good way to do it, an exception will ruin it.  Clearly he needs to subscribe the event when *client* is created.  Simple and fail-safe.  If you can't post a better answer because that code is missing from the question then at least put it in a finally block.

Comment: @HansPassant in order to put it in a finally block i would need to put the whole function body in a try catch ?? am i right ??

Comment: @HansPassant Wow, did you wake up on the wrong side of the bed? As far as I'm concerned, the question was not about how to do proper Exception handling, but rather why an event was firing multiple times.

Comment: @MagnusJohansson umm he told me how to solve my problem efficiently .. how is that bad??

Comment: @Raiden It's not that I'm question the logical correctness of his Exception handling comment, it's more the patronizing "If you can't post a better answer.." bitter tone that I reacted on. He had 2 options; either post his own answer or putting down mine, and he chose the latter.

Comment: @Magnus - You are getting this wrong, "putting down" an answer is pretty simple at SO, I could have downvoted it.  I didn't, I improved it at the OP's request.  It is one of the key features of SO.  You could make derogatory remarks about my haircut, if that makes you feel better :)

Comment: (the answer) is so simple..yet so frustrating.  my constructor and a method were wiring up the event handlers twice.